# passing userid and password in xml request

Tags: json, xml, vba, ms-access, msxml

I have a potential client who wants to pull some data from a website via VBA.  I am new to XML and JSON.

I found a link somewhere that provides the following code which uses MSXML to return data for a single item from that particular website.

```
Public Function GetItemSalePrice(item As String) As Double
Dim dblItem As Long
With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
    .Open "GET", "http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/item/" & item, False
    .send
    dblItem = Split(Split(.responsetext, "min_sale_unit_price"":")(1), ",")(0)
    GetItemSalePrice = dblItem / 100
End With
End Function
```

However, the data my client wants to return comes in pages of up to 500 records at a time.  He indicates that the 
he wants to pass in date ranges, and a page number, similar to the following.

https://api.appfigures.com/v2/reviews?client_key=xxxxxxxf&start=2015-01-01&end=2016-01-21&page=1

But because this is an https site, it wants a userid and password.  Can I simply reformat that string to include userid and password?  Or is there another method or property of the MSXML object that can be set for authentication?

The client indicates that the return value looks like:

```
{
"total": 140,
"pages": 28,
"this_page": 1,
"reviews": [{
    "author": "DeveloperToDeveloper",
    "title": "Just Spectacular",
    "review": "Finally able to remove the ads! The description is hilarious!! Thanks!!!",
    "original_title": null,
    "original_review": null,
    "stars": "5.00",
    "iso": "US",
    "version": "1.2",
    "date": "2012-09-19T17:05:00",
    "product": 6567539,
    "weight": 0,
    "id": "5561747L7xnbsMRu8UbPvy7A71Dv6A=="
}]
}
```

But with multiple records returned, as many as 500 at a time.  Is there an efficient way of reading data in that format into a table? One or more records at a time?  I can obviously write a text parser but I assume that someone has probably already done that leg work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] to get a better idea of what constitutes a "good" question. Specifically, this question covers at least three separate issues: (1) connecting to a web service with authentication, (2) sending it a search request with parameters, and (3) importing the results it returns. They should be distinct questions.

Comment: HTTPS has nothing to do with requiring authentication.  Also see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757849(v=vs.85).aspx for the `.open` method's signature.  For that matter there are several JSON parsers that have been or can be adapted to VBA.

Answer (score 0):

thanks Bob.  If figured out the authentication issue, a popup dialog is used to enter userid and password and the client was satisfied with that.

And given the structure of the returned string, I was able to parse the data myself without too much difficulty.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't look at the link provided above.  User/PW can be passed to the `open` method, you don't have to wait for a popup dialog.